# How can I switch between multiple views using a single java class?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, onclicklistener

I inherited an Android Studio project with basically no experience with Java programming.  I've been going through and teaching myself using free online tutorials and The Big Nerd Ranch guide book and I know how to switch to different .xml views using associated .java classes, but I want to open a new .xml view associated with the same .java class.

Basically I just want to modify the app I have which reads information from a Bluetooth device and displays measurements in a TextView along with a "Pass/Fail" display to having a pass/fail display and a "View Log" button that when clicked, takes you to a new .xml that contains the TextView with all the results.

I'm trying to avoid using a different .java class because I want all of the items to have the same functions, just on different .xml views, and I'm worried that moving everything I already have into a new .java class will just create more problems than I already have.

I'm not sure if it's necessary, but here is my code:
From my starting screen

```
frament_bluetooth_scanner.xml:
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/go_to_log"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:text="@string/view_log"
        android:textSize="20dp"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="#ccc"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/margin_small"
    android:paddingLeft="4dp"
    android:paddingRight="4dp"
    android:paddingBottom="4dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_present"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ffc4ab"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:text="NO TAGGANT DETECTED"
        android:textSize="26dp"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

`button_present` both activates the Bluetooth test and displays the pass/fail results.  It was existing and is working as expected.

`go_to_log` is a button I added and I want it to click to take me to the next  view:

```
view_list.xml:
<FrameLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="4dp"
    android:paddingRight="4dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="@string/clear_log"
        android:id="@+id/button_clear_log" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:paddingTop="40dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:id="@+id/scanLogView"
        android:maxLines = "4096"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:scrollbars = "vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

All of this code was originally in the `fragment_bluetooth_scanner.xml` file and everything worked as expected.  The only problem is that the `TextView` was hard to read because it displayed information for all the tests until it was cleared, and all the information didn't fit on the screen for even a single test.  I want to change it to be more user friendly.

The main .java file is quite long so I'll post the relevant portions of it.
From `ScannerFragment.java`:

```
 @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle 
savedInstanceState) {
    SP = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());

    mPowerOffButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_poweroff);
    mDisconnectButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_disconnect);
    mConnectButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_connect);
    mPresence = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_present);

    mBattery = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

    mBlinkConnect = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_connectionblink);
    mBlinkData = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_communication);
    mClearLog = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_clear_log);

    mDeviceName = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_devicename);
    mDeviceSN = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_devicesn);
    mBatteryPerc = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.label_batterypct);

    mReadingLog  = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.scanLogView);
    mReadingLog.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
    mReadingLog.setText(readFromFile());

    mViewLog = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.go_to_log);


    telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)getContext().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

    initLocationService(this.getContext());

    final ActionBar actionBar = getActivity().getActionBar();
    if (null == actionBar) {
        return;
    }
    final Drawable D = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.stardust2);
    actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(D);
    actionBar.setTitle("");



}

private void setupScanner() {
    Log.d(TAG, "setupScanner()");

    // Initialize the send button with a listener that for click events
    mPowerOffButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(isIris) {
                publishMessage(Constants.COMMAND_POWEROFF_IRIS);
            } else {
                publishMessage(Constants.COMMAND_POWEROFF);
            }
            mScannerService.stop();
        }
    });

    // Initialize the send button with a listener that for click events
    mDisconnectButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Send a message using content of the edit text widget
            publishMessage(Constants.COMMAND_DISCONNECT);
            mScannerService.stop();
        }
    });

    // Initialize the send button with a listener that for click events
    mConnectButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Send a message using content of the edit text widget
            publishMessage(Constants.COMMAND_ON_CONNECT);
        }
    });

    mClearLog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Send a message using content of the edit text widget
            mReadingLog.setText("");
            if(SP.getBoolean("writeToFile", true)) {
                writeToFile("", "", false);
            }
        }
    });
```

This is where all the existing actions take place.  The main thing that deters me from creating a new .java class is that `mReadingLog` is used all throughout this class, and I don't understand reading/writing text files very well at this point, so I want to avoid altering anything that has to do with that process.

I've gone through tutorials in the past such as [this one](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html), but I can't find anything on how to open a new `xml` file while associating in with the same `.java` class.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure i understood. But If you want to switch between different views by the press of a button or ... you can use [ViewFilpper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html).
Add it as a View in your activity layout.

```
<ViewFlipper
   android:id="@+id/simpleViewFlipper"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">

   <!--   Add View’s Here Which You Want to Flip -- > 
   <include layout="First"/>
   <include layout="Second"/>
   <include layout="third"/>
   <!-- ... -->

</ ViewFlipper >
```

Comment: Thank you for the response!  This works extremely well and saved me so much time and headache.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

... OK, so I actually read it this time... lol... you can create function in a single class. Make that static and then you can call those functions anywhere.

This is what I do

```
public class MethodContants {

    public static void showLog(String tag, String logMessage, boolean error) {
        if (error) {
            Log.e(tag, logMessage);
        } else {
            Log.i(tag, logMessage);
        }
    }

    public static String showStringResource(int resource) {
        return getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(resource);
    }


}
```

So in any of my classes, I can call like so:

```
MethodConstants.showLog(TAG, "message", true);
```

Comment: thanks for the reply!  To make sure I understand thing correctly, `MethodContacts` is your main java class, so for me I would make my function in `public class ScannerFragment...` and the function you posted is just an example of a static function that can be called from anywhere in any class?  Should I make a separate class that relates to my new xml file and then make the function that my new class refers to static in the original java file, and then call these function as described at the end of your solution?

Comment: When a method is static, you can call it anywhere in your classes. But you need to really be careful to make sure you make things private that should be. I put all of my functions in one class and make it static. These two are perfect examples because one is a log and the other is the R.string. resource. But, if you are changing colors, for eample, create one functions that is static and call it whereever. hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: I think this is the best way to approach my problem but I don't have the knowledge to go through such a large project and declare everything correctly.  I ended up using viewFlipper, which solves my problem but doesn't seem to be as smooth as I would like it to be